# Import error in Python while importing some constants

Tags: python

```
#constants.py

TAU = 5.55555

ref_X =  95.047
ref_Y = 100.000
ref_Z = 108.883

def main():
    DTEP = {}
    DTEP['1'] = 1.22222
```

Now if I Import TAU like this :

```
from constants import TAU
```

There is no error but if I import DTEP by same method it shows this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name DTEP
```

Now why this error? Either it should be able to import all the constants or none. Why this partiality with DTEP?

Adding the full code (The name is DTEP1 here, I know):

```
TAU = 5.55555

import shelve

ref_X =  95.047
ref_Y = 100.000
ref_Z = 108.883
DTEP1 = {}

def main():
    d = shelve.open("tables/DTEP_132758.txt")
    for k in xrange(0,132758):
        DTEP1[str(k)] = rgb_to_cielab(d[str(k)][0], d[str(k)][1], d[str(k)][2])
    print DTEP1['1223']



def rgb_to_xyz(R, G, B):
    '''
    Convert from RGB to XYZ.
    '''
    var_R = ( R / 255.)
    var_G = ( G / 255.)
    var_B = ( B / 255.)

    if var_R > 0.04045:
        var_R = ( ( var_R + 0.055 ) / 1.055 ) ** 2.4
    else:
        var_R /= 12.92

    if var_G > 0.04045:
        var_G = ( ( var_G + 0.055 ) / 1.055 ) ** 2.4
    else:
        var_G /= 12.92
    if var_B > 0.04045:
        var_B = ( ( var_B + 0.055 ) / 1.055 ) ** 2.4
    else:
        var_B /= 12.92

    var_R *= 100
    var_G *= 100
    var_B *= 100

    #Observer. = 2 deg, Illuminant = D65
    X = var_R * 0.4124 + var_G * 0.3576 + var_B * 0.1805
    Y = var_R * 0.2126 + var_G * 0.7152 + var_B * 0.0722
    Z = var_R * 0.0193 + var_G * 0.1192 + var_B * 0.9505

    return X,Y,Z


#-------------------------------------------------#
def xyz_to_cielab(X, Y, Z):
    '''
    Convert from XYZ to CIE-L*a*b*
    '''
    var_X = X / ref_X
    var_Y = Y / ref_Y
    var_Z = Z / ref_Z

    if var_X > 0.008856:
        var_X **= ( 1./3. )
    else:
        var_X = ( 7.787 * var_X ) + ( 16. / 116. )
    if var_Y > 0.008856:
        var_Y **= ( 1./3. )
    else:
        var_Y = ( 7.787 * var_Y ) + ( 16. / 116. )
    if var_Z > 0.008856:
        var_Z **= ( 1./3. )
    else:
        var_Z = ( 7.787 * var_Z ) + ( 16. / 116. )

    CIE_L = ( 116 * var_Y ) - 16.
    CIE_a = 500. * ( var_X - var_Y )
    CIE_b = 200. * ( var_Y - var_Z )

    return CIE_L, CIE_a, CIE_b


#-------------------------------------------------#
def rgb_to_cielab(R, G, B):
    '''
    Convert from RGB to CIE-L*a*b*.
    '''
    X,Y,Z = rgb_to_xyz(R,G,B)
    return xyz_to_cielab(X,Y,Z)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `DTEP` is defined in a function, not in a global context.

Comment: Why do you have a method defined in a module called `constants.py`? If you're not going to execute them, they do nothing. (There is nothing special about functions named `main` in Python; they are not automatically executed upon importing a module.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DTEP` is in the scope of the `main` function. Only variables defined at the module level (like `TAU` and `ref_X`) can be imported.

In this case, the problem could be solved simply by moving the original definition of `DTEP` (but not necessarily the lines that populate it) out of the `main` function:

```
DTEP = {}

def main():
    DTEP['1'] = 1.22222

main()
```

Alternatively, you could use the `global` keyword in the `main` function (though note that that works only if you call `main()` from the module level at some point):

```
def main():
    global DTEP
    DTEP = {}
    DTEP['1'] = 1.22222

main()
```

Perhaps the best solution is just to have everything at the same level, getting rid of the `main` function:

```
TAU = 5.55555

ref_X =  95.047
ref_Y = 100.000
ref_Z = 108.883

DTEP = {}
DTEP['1'] = 1.22222
```

Comment: Okay but how to get the value of DTEP then?

Comment: @user1786791 Move it out of main? Like after TAU?

Comment: Okay let me try to define it globally

Comment: @user1786791: See the latest edits, which offer two solutions

Comment: The first one which you suggested is importing only empty DTEP. The values added in main() are not being imported.

Comment: @user1786791: That's because you never call the `main()` function. I had assumed it was being called. Add the line `main()`. (Though as others have noted, why even have a `main` function at all?)

Comment: Yeah that was there I just didnt ctrl+v that here. main is being called as I have tried some print functions in that. but still the values are not being imported.

Comment: Is `main` being called within `constants.py`? Could you post the full code?

Comment: @user1786791: That never calls `main()`- or more specifically, it never calls `main()` when it is imported. The entire purpose of `if __name__ == "__main__"` is to avoid executing when a script is imported. Thus, either take `main()` out of the `if` block, or take any code you want to happen before importing (like that defines `DTEP1`) out of the `main` function.

Comment: I tried moving the main() out of the if block, It was showing the same output i.e empty dictionary when imported. And when I tried to move everything inside main outside of that, then function rgb_to_clab is not being called. And it is showing the error that rgb_tp_clab is not found.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25580/discussion-between-user1786791-and-david-robinson)